# need help to read a file in python

Tags: python

I am new to python but I have learned lots of stuff, but I found difficulty to read a JSON file. I need to read it in a way to access a particular data in this file. The file contain a data as follow:

```
[
    29723,
    5426523,
    "this book need to be printed",
    "http://amzn.to/U60TaF"
][
    29723,
    807242528,
    "ready for shipping",
    "http://nblo.gs/HNpn"
]
```

my code is:

```
FI = open(file_name, 'r')
for line in FI:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    print(tweet)
```

The output is only the last line which is the link, I don't know way.

Comment: If it *"looks like a json file"*, but isn't a json file, then you cannot use `json` to read it. You need to have a specification of the file, and then use a reader made for that. If it does not exist, you have to write you own. There is no *"almost like a X"* in programming. Computers are too precise for that.

Comment: Thanks, you probably right

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
data = json.load(open(file_name))
```

Comment: @AlghamdiBandar can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error, it just gave the last line of each block which is the link

Comment: Can you share link to your sample code and sample file which you are trying to parse? You can use http://pastebin.com/index.php for sharing code.